# What is Requirement to Unlock [Unique Skills]?

Tags: sword-art-online

According to [Kawahara Reki](https://www.reddit.com/r/anime/comments/29y8mj/my_summary_of_kawahara_reki_sao_panel_at_ax/) there supposed to be 10 [Unique Skills] on Sword Art Online. I know few of them.

- Dual Blades = Player with Fastest Reaction speed.
- Holy Sword = Strongest Player (GM giving himself the strongest player title)
- Darkness Sword = Highest Player Killing count.

All [Unique Skills] should be rewarded after Floor 90. What are other [Unique Skills] and requirement to unlock it ?

Comment: i think the part about all the Unique Skills being awarded after Floor 90 is only because after Floor 90 Kayaba had planned to reveal that he was Heathcliff and more than likely give up his unique skill going to the next strongest. also could you state where you got the requirement for the Darkness Blade from? on the [wikia](http://swordartonline.wikia.com/wiki/Unique_Skills) which lists some of the skills only Duel Blades and Holy Sword have their listed requirements

Comment: no, i think he would lead frontliners as Heatcliff untill Floor 100 where there was no town, no dungeon, no mobs, only single throne in the middle of white boss room, then he will walk calmly leaving all frontliners to sit on that throne, and  said "Welcome" in a tone befitting of a God.

Comment: and Darkness Blade requirement is from some interview with Kawahara-Sensei, i`ll look for it again.

Comment: [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/anime/comments/29y8mj/my_summary_of_kawahara_reki_sao_panel_at_ax/) it is interview translation

Comment: no Kayaba said on Floor 75 that his original plan was to reveal himself before the 100th floor but i think he said it was Floor 90 he would reveal himself but i know he defiantly wasn't waiting until floor 100. in the grand scheme of things if he waited till the very last moment he would have the unfair advantage of knowing everyone skills up until that point which would kinda contradict what the wikia says about him having a level of honor and fairness

Comment: pffft , what honour , when pvp againts Kirito for the first time he  admitted using System Assist Mod. . . .

Comment: well the Wikia, and Kayaba, did say that Duel Blades was meant for the person who was to face him on the final floor (along with fastest reaction time). thinking on that it would explain why he wanted Kirito to use his Duel Blades in the Duel and seeing how he almost lost he had Kirito loose as to make him join the Guild so he could be there when Kayaba revealed himself.

Comment: Thats it, someone has really got to make this into a first person MMO (whether or not it's on Rift or Vive....lol)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Up until now, only 2 [Unique Skill] have been mentioned in the story:

- 二刀流 (Dual Blades): fastest reaction speed
- 神聖剣 (Holy Sword): strongest player

However, according to a web-anquette interview (cannot find the original source),

> Q...他にユニークスキルなど考えてましたか？
>   A...90層以降、更に８種のユニークスキルがアンロックされる予定だった。『暗黒剣』『抜刀術』『手裏剣術』『無限槍』など……デザインに苦労したんだが……。
>
> Q...Have you thought about the other [Unique Skill]?
>   A...Above Floor 90, 8 more [Unique Skill] have been planned to be unlocked. Examples are (see below), but there were troubles about the design...
>
> - 暗黒剣 (Darkness Sword): highest PK count (if-situation at floor 95, Kirito vs PoH)
> - 抜刀術 (Swordsmanship)
> - 手裏剣術 (Shuriken Technique)
> - 無限槍 (Infinite Spear)

Note that since they are still in planning, the real [Unique Skill] might be different.

---

References:

- [SAO Fan Wiki (Japanese)](https://www33.atwiki.jp/swordart-online/pages/27.html#id_6742077b)
- Japanese Yahoo! Answers: [1](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1385607793), [2](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13146520273), [3](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q14108245729)
- [Arcadia (Japanese BBS)](http://www.mai-net.net/bbs/mainbbs/mainbbs.php?act=dump&cate=zatudan&all=6940&n=0#0)